# Why doesn't my query succeed? (PHP MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, insert

there is something wrong with my query but I have no idea what the problem is.

Here are my queries:

```
$result=mysql_query("UPDATE user_info SET Money = '$newmoney' WHERE Username ='$user'"); 

$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO order (username, amount, stock, company) VALUES 
('$user','$amount','$stock','$symbol')");
```

When I run it the first query works, but the second doesn't. There are now errors given.
Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: I tried that and it says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (username, amount, stock, company) VALUES (username,23, 15.84,YHOO)' at line 1"

Comment: That error does not have `'` around your parameters.  Either your query or your error message are not identical to what you have posted here.  I also ***strongly*** advise against Building your queries this way; you get no type safety, more difficult debugging and all the SQL injection attacks under the sun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html).  Quote it with backticks:

```
$result = mysql_query("
  INSERT INTO `order`
    (username, amount, stock, company)
  VALUES
    ('$user','$amount','$stock','$symbol')
");
```

Furthermore, notice that on the PHP manual page for the [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function, it states in a **big red box**:

> #### Suggested alternatives
>
> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - [mysqli_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
> - [PDO::query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

Comment: I tried this and still it gives the same error message. Thank you anyway.

Comment: hope you used backticks and not single quote on the ORDER table?

Comment: @user1760791: From the error message you posted in [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990917/why-doesnt-my-query-succeed-php-mysql/12990975#comment17622348_12990917), it appears that you are not quoting your string literals.  When you switch to PDO or mysqli, you should use [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/623041) instead, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Really look fine, can you try this?

```
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO order (username, amount, stock, company) VALUES 
($user,$amount,$stock,$symbol)");
```

Comment: I tried this and it says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (username, amount, stock, company) VALUES (username,23, 15.84,YHOO)' at line 1"

Comment: Hint: what goes around string literals in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated order is a reserved mysql word. In this link you can find other reserved words: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html, Instead of using backticks I would change the column's name it would be easier.